# create table from data from other tables and with user defined constraints constraints

Tags: sql-server

The following two tables are used to define users and their respective roles:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
     id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE roles 
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

The users_roles table should contain the mapping between each user and their roles.
Each user can have many roles, and each role can have many users. Modify the provided SQLite create table statement so that:

1. Only users from the users table can exist within users_roles.
2. Only roles from the roles table can exist within users_roles.
3. A user can only have a specific role once.

   CREATE TABLE users_roles 
   (
         userId INTEGER, 
         roleId INTEGER 
   )

I have tried

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles 
(
    userId integer NOT NULL,
    roleId integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId, roleId),
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (roleId) REFERENCES roles(id)
)
```

it solves many of these problem but there is one big problem.

If in the roles table there are duplicates e.g

```
id | role
---+-------
 1 | hr
 2 | hr
 3 | cse
```

in the users_roles tables there is still

```
users.id | roles.id
---------+----------
    1    |    1
    1    |    2
```

users id 1 matches with both roles id 1 and 2. but 1 and 2 have role hr, thus it violates the last bullet point.

What more I have to do in the create `user_roles` table so that I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is it SQLLite or SQL Server ?

Comment: The problem is your `Roles` table, not the `User_roles` table.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent duplicates on the roles table by adding a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [roles] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [UC_roles_role] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([role] ASC)
                   WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```